# Why labelling an eigenstate with quantum number $\ell$ instead of $j$?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, angular-momentum, hilbert-space, atomic-physics

Solving time-indepedent Schrodinger equation for an electron moving in an effective potential will find that energy eigenvalue depends on the quantum numbers $n$ and $\ell$. My question is why we end up with the quantum number $l$ but not quantum number $j$ which is the total angular momentum (orbital and spin angular momenta)? Does it mean spin angular momentum have zero energy? In addition, why we not include spin eigenstate when solving Schrodinger equation?

Comment: The energy of a pure Coulomb potential and no spin depends only on $n$; it does not depend on $\ell$, and it does not depend on $j$ either.

Comment: What do you mean by pure Coulomb potential? When solving the Schrodinger equation using spherical polar coordinates, you will end up with an effective potential with $\ell$ dependence.

Comment: pure Coulomb means Coulomb. The effecive potential depends on $\ell$ but the energies do not. Recall that $E_n=-13\ \mathrm{eV}\ \frac{1}{n^2}$.

Comment: Okay then for effective potential, why we don't label an eigenstate with quantum number $j$ but $\ell$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$j$ is reserved for total spin, as you point out, whereas $\ell$ is strictly angular momentum and must be an integer.

The states $\vert jm_j\rangle $ are of the form
$$
\vert jm_j\rangle =\sum_{m_\ell m_s}C_{\ell m_\ell;sm_s}^{jm_j}\vert\ell m_\ell\rangle \vert sm_s\rangle
$$
with $C_{\ell m_\ell;sm_s}^{jm_j}$ a Clebsch-Gordan coefficient.  These states are useful for the evaluation of terms like the spin-orbit interaction $H_{so}\sim \vec \ell\cdot\vec s$.  Hence, the spin can actually contribute to the energy of a state, although not from a spatial-only potential.

When solving the Schrodinger equation for a spatial potential, the spin degree of freedom plays no role: it just "factors out" and can be ignored.

Comment: Okay so quantum number $s$ does play a role in total energy, but it is not involved in solving the Schrodinger equation for a spatial potential. It is the bit where I am confused. Why spin is not solved in the coordinate space? Is it correct to assume spin does have spatial coordinates?

Comment: Spin does NOT have "spatial coordinates": there is no equivalent to the spherical harmonics for spin. In this sense spin is a degree of freedom with no spatial extent.